# Equivalent of cftchapternumwidth when using book class?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir, document-classes

I have the following to modify table of contents spacing when using `memoir`:

```latex
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0.5em}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{10em}
```

What is the equivalent when using the `book` class?

Comment: Just use `tocloft`?

Comment: As Johannes mentions, memoirs macros stem from tocloft, though the memoir macro names might be slightly different. Otherwise just 6se memoir ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.5em}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10em}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example using [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0.5em}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{10em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is a replication of the output using [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) in the `book` document class (note that chapter-level lengths for the ToC under `tocloft` uses `\cftchap...`, not `\cftchapter...` as is used with `memoir`):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.5em}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10em}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

---

Without any packages, you'll have to change the definition of `\l@chapter`. Here's the original definition from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co):

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

Here's the updated definition to replicate the behaviour of `memoir` and/or `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0.5em% <----------------- Similar to \cftbeforechapskip from tocloft
    \setlength\@tempdima{10em}% <--- Similar to \cftchapnumwidth from tocloft
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```